# Pure Azure AD joined windows 10 Smart card windows login

Tags: active-directory, azure-active-directory, certificate, smartcard, winlogon

In my company we enroll smart card to users for them to login into their workstations/Laptop. We are moving to Azure AD and want to continue using smart card login with laptops joined to Azure Ad, thereby removing on-prem AD very soon.

My question is how can smart card based windows logon be used with pure azure ad domain joined windows 10 machines.

Also we use a 3rd party CA for these smart cards.

Answer (score 0):

Smartcards can be used to sign in to Azure AD joined devices if you have AD FS configured.

Recommendation: we can Implement Windows Hello for Business for strong, password-less authentication to Windows 10 devices.

Comment: Do you happen to have any msdn link about this integration with a 3rd party CA?

Comment: ADFS means Azure environment needs to be federated? Is there a way without deploying adfs? Also that means AD needs to be present with ADFS , correct? removing on-prem AD is not an option?

Comment: Yes, ADFS  is required to use Smart cards for authentication. Please check this for Implementation scenarios https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/devices/azureadjoin-plan#review-your-scenarios